Build failed. @parcel/core: node_modules/pg-cloudflare/dist/empty.js does not export 'CloudflareSocket'
I'm building a webapp using Parcel to bundle.
Everything was working right at the front, but then I started the back setting the data base and got this error from parcel.
 Build failed.

@parcel/core: node_modules/pg-cloudflare/dist/empty.js does not export 'CloudflareSocket'

  C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\carrera\nivel-3\modulo-7\desafio-m7\node_modules\pg\lib\stream.js:10:13
     9 |   } else {
  > 10 |     const { CloudflareSocket } = require('pg-cloudflare')
  >    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    11 |     return new CloudflareSocket(ssl)
    12 |   }

This is my sequelize setting
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize"
require('dotenv').config();
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.SEQUELIZE_ACCOUNT_URL, {
    host: 'host-name',
    dialectModule: require('pg'),
    sync: {
        alter: true
    },
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            require: true
        }
    }
});

This is my package.json
{
  "name": "mvc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "source": "src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "dev:parcel": "parcel",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch ./endpoints.ts --exec \"ts-node\" endpoints.ts",
    "dev:endpoints": "nodemon --watch ./be-src/endpoints.ts --exec ts-node ./be-src/endpoints.ts",
    "build": "parcel build",
    "sync": "ts-node ./be-src/sync.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.22",
    "@vaadin/router": "vaadin/router",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.23.3",
    "cloudinary": "^2.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "dropzone": "^6.0.0-beta.2",
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "parcel": "^2.12.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "buffer": "^5.5.0||^6.0.0",
    "console-browserify": "^1.2.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "events": "^3.1.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.11.5",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.1.0",
    "string_decoder": "^1.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "util": "^0.12.3",
    "vm-browserify": "^1.1.2"
  }
}

I'm pretty new at this, so if more info may be needed to give me some help, I'll be glad to give it.
I hope someone can help me, I've been for more than a week now, looking through the entire internet for documentation to help me get this solve but didn't find anything
I tried changing the Sequelize db config from:
  dialectModule: require('pg')

to an import, like this:
import pg from 'pg'

 dialectModule: pg

also tried using webpack, but because I've never used it before, I though it would make the headache even worst
